# R: Accessing vectors with integer names

Tags: r

I have a large function which has a vector defined as follows:

```
v <- mat.or.vec(length(communities), 1)
names(v) <- communities
```

And, I access the elements of `v` in a loop as follows

```
for(c in communities){
  v[c] = 1
}
```

When this code was written and tested, the list `communities` was a list of strings. But today when I ran this on a dataset which had all integer values in the `communities` list, my function crashed. It took me a while to figure out that when `communities` is a integer list, `c` is an integer and `v[c]` access the c<sup>th</sup> element of `v` and not the element of `v` with name `c`.

I can fix this problem by using something like `v[as.character(c)]`. There are many such variables which face the same problem.

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the simplest change is in the `for` statement:

```
for(c in as.character(communities)){
  v[c] = 1
}
```

Or vectorized:

```
v[as.character(communities)] <- 1
```

Or to have even more control you could do the match yourself:

```
idx <- match(communities, names(v))
v[idx] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to name the elements of a vector -- kind of a waste.  Why not just do

```
v <- mat.or.vec(length(communities), 1)  # or better: v<- rep(NA,length(communities)  
for (i in 1: length(communities)) { 
     v[i] <- 1  
 }
```

But if you need to work with the values of the elements of `communities` , then you will need to include some quote marks:

```
Rgames> mat.or.vec(3, 1)->bar
Rgames> names(bar)<-4:6
Rgames> bar
4 5 6 
0 0 0 
Rgames> bar['4']
4 
0 
Rgames> bar[4]
<NA> 
 NA
```

I'm assuming that you provided a simplified example, and you need to do something more complicated than simply setting the value of all elements of `v` to 1 .

Comment: Yea, I needed to far more complicated things than assigning to 1. I couldn't include quotation marks because I had no control over how communities was generated.